# image height increases on every reload

Tags: iphone, css, safari, responsive-design, media-queries

I've got an image-tag with a width of 200 and height of 206 and stretched it proportional to full window width by using `width="100%"` and `height="auto"`

It works well on IE10, IE9, Safari, Chrome and Firefox but on my iPhone 3G the image is stretched to 100% height and when I reload the image height gets doubled!

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/EXgBB/1/) so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `position:auto` on nested parent DIVs solved the problem